# Skip three post in wordpress post loop

Tags: wordpress

how can I skip three posts in **wordpress** post loop? Thanks.

```
while ( $query_custom->have_posts() ) : $query_custom->the_post();
    include( locate_template( 'content-' . $style . '.php' ) );
endwhile;
```

Comment: do you want to skip any 3 post, first 3 or last?

Comment: First 3 posts! Thanks :)

Comment: try answered solution and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in functions.php

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'skip_posts_wordpress');
function skip_posts_wordpress($query){

    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_archive()){
        $query->set('offset', 3);
    }
}
```

OR try

```
$query_custom = new WP_Query( array( 'offset' => 3 ) );
 while ( $query_custom->have_posts() ) : $query_custom->the_post();
      include( locate_template( 'content-' . $style . '.php' ) );
 endwhile;
```

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is the better method.

Comment: The second code works! but i'm facing an issue where there is a "load more" button on the post, so after clicking the load more the posts displayed are duplicated. Should i post the whole theme file codes here to find out what is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add:

```
$query_custom = new WP_Query( array( 'offset' => 3 ) );

while ( $query_custom->have_posts() ) : $query_custom->the_post();
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm still facing an issue where there is a "load more" button on the post, so after clicking the button the posts displayed are duplicated. Should i post the whole theme file codes here to find out what is causing it?

Comment: have just send you a question! Really glad for your help! Thanks!